# Database Design for oauth2

Tags: php, laravel, oauth

I have a users table that looks like so:

[image]

Currently my email is set to unique. And when user tries to login, I check the email and password, and if it matches, I send a token . But now I want to enable login using oauth providers(G+, Facebook, github etc). 
To achieve this, I decided to use Laravel's socialite plugin. In the docs, it says:

```
Retrieving User Details

Once you have a user instance, you can grab a few more details about the user:

$user = Socialite::driver('github')->user();

// OAuth Two Providers
$token = $user->token;

// OAuth One Providers
$token = $user->token;
$tokenSecret = $user->tokenSecret;

// All Providers
$user->getId();
$user->getNickname();
$user->getName();
$user->getEmail();
$user->getAvatar();
```

My question is, once the oauth is successful, how do I save the details in the database. 
What changes should I make in the table.

Comment: add another table that connects to the user named 'social providers' contains google, fb, twitter, github columns and what knot. auth always returns an id and that's what you'll use to identify the user.

Comment: if I do that , the password field of my users table will need to be left blank. 
I don't know how to handle that

Comment: thats ok, just make a "confirm page" after they login/auth requiring necessary info like passwords, username and email. and then update the database after that, this is for security reasons am I right? And this is good to consolidate preceeding thirdparty auths too for the same account.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't plan to make any requests on behalf of user, you actually don't even need to save OAuth access tokens – you could simple log users in once social authentication is passed. A typical flow:

1. See if user exists already, eg. $user = User::whereEmail($user->getEmail());
2. If user doesn't exist, create one using User::create([]), take as much data as possible from social network. If user exists, you may want to update his avatar/name with values from the social network.
3. Log user in using Auth::login($user);

If you do however plan to do some extra requests on behalf of user, you would need to store access token somewhere (in a separate database table, for example). Most social networks would require you to save one long string – access token, and Twitter needs two – access token and a secret. So at the very least your table will contain: user ID from your users table, social provider ID and access token.

If you save access tokens, you can do API requests on behalf of users – check their timelines, post, etc.

Comment: say the user does not exist. I create A user using User::create(). But there is not going be to any password that I can obtain from 3rd party login , right ?
How can I handle that ?

Comment: A common practice – generate a random password for user (maybe even send to him by email?) so in case the user wants to log in manually one day in the future - they can do it. Laravel even has a helper function for this - str_random(length). Another possibility - put empty/null password so that user won't be able to log in using email and password, but have 'Reset password' functionality somewhere on the site

Answer (score 0):

You could perhaps check this repository:

https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel

If you don't want to use the package, you can just check out the database migration files and controllers to see how the logins and registrations are handled.